# Windows doesn't recognize the GPU

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

Today I have updated Windows 10 to the latest version, unfortunately, when I tried to open GeForce Experience there was this message:

> Version: 3.5.0.70, NVIDIA GeForce Experience requires a Nvidia GPU

I have an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070 inside my PC since last month.

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From This PC icon click on Manage. In Computer Management click on Device Manager -> Display Drivers -> Your GPU card -> Update driver -> Search automatically for updated driver software.

[image: update gpu driver]

Answer (score 0):

It is a common upgrade problem: 
Uninstall the whole nvidia stuff from Add/Remove programs, do a reboot and go to [nvidia site](http://www.nvidia.com) to download the right drivers to your machine.